# How can I divide a file into sections and put them in a dictionary using robot framework

Tags: dictionary, robotframework

I have a file that goes like this:

```
Name: John
Class: II
Age:  8
Interest: Sports

Name: Emma
Class: III
Hobby: Dance
```

So I want to read this file and put the contents into a dictionary with Name as key. The sections vary in number of lines. How can I achieve this dictionary using Robot Framework keywords.

Comment: the simplest solution would be to write a keyword in python. Is that an acceptable solution, or do you need to do this all using built-in keywords?

Comment: I need to use only builtin-keywords. But just to be aware, would like to know the python implementation as well.

Comment: there is no simple way to do what you want with built-in keywords. It's likely achievable, but will require a lot of code. you need to read the file, split it into lines, loop over the lines, and create a dictionary.  As written, this question is just too broad. You should  try to solve the problem yourself, and then come back when you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    String
Library    Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Split File By Names
    ${my_dict}    Create Dictionary
    ${data}    Get File    <path_to_your_data>
    @{lines}    Split To Lines    ${data}
    Remove Values From List    ${lines}    ${EMPTY}
    :FOR    ${line}    IN    @{lines}
    \    ${key}    ${value}    Split String    ${line}    :
    \    ${name}    Set Variable If    '${key}' == 'Name'    ${value.strip()}    ${name}
    \    Run Keyword If    '${key}' == 'Name'    Set To Dictionary    ${my_dict}    ${name}=@{EMPTY}
    \    Run Keyword If    '${key}' <> 'Name'    Append To List    ${my_dict.${name}}    ${line}
    Log    ${my_dict}
```

Anyway, the RF way to parse the file sucks. I would rather go for python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class ParseFile:

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_dict = {}

    def parse_file_to_dict(self):
        with open('<path_to_your_data>') as f:
            lines = f.read().splitlines()
            for line in (l for l in lines if l != ""):
                key, value = line.split(":", 1)
                if key == "Name":
                    name = value
                    self.my_dict[name] = []
                else:
                    self.my_dict[name].append(line)
        return self.my_dict
```

... and then just call it in RF.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ParseFile.py

*** Test Cases ***
Do It In Python
    ${my_dict}    Parse File To Dict
    Log    ${my_dict}
```

Please note that both ways are strictly tight to data structure you provided. I.e. if "Name" is not at the first line of each section, it will not work and will need more handling with the data.

Comment: Little tweak to bring suitable output and this code works exactly well for me. Thanks a ton! 

I had a failure in this line so had to lose them and use a Create List before the loop and Append. 
 \    Run Keyword If    '${key}' <> 'Name'    Append To List    ${my_dict.${name}}    ${line}

Comment: I'm glad it works. Anyway it would be nice to increase robustness for case of incorrect/incomplete data - and that's the moment when python solution is really worthy because it is much more flexible.